# Putting Login logic in partial view

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have almost developed a Attendance app in MVC , linq to sql, as a newbie. Now stuck at one place, LOGGED IN section, When a session for particular user begins than LOGOUT Button appears on right top corner, That's ok but what i want to do i so get an id (employee id) being stored in session currently and then displaying that at top right corner like

```
EMPLOYEE 002 has Logged in,
[LOG OUT]
```

[image]

LogOut is actually a partial view being rendered i which i have put my logic for session checking.

```
@if(Session["Employee"] != null) {
    @*<text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!*@
   <text> [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log In", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```

Controller for Logout

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            Session.Abandon();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: what happens when you use @User.Identity.Name?

Comment: What is the problem again? You don't know how to get an employee id or how to display it?

Comment: Why do you test on a `Session` object? You need to call `Request.IsAuthenticated` for that. If you store some kind of info in `Session["Employee"]`, maybe even the employee ID, then just replace `@User.Identity.Name` with `@Session["Employee"]`. Please do not that that's bad practice...

Comment: @AndreiV SOUDNS GREAT, PLEASE COULD U ELABORATE MORE

Comment: I will, but I need more info from you. Where are you storing this employee ID that you want to display? Is it stored in the `Session` object or do you have an "app settings" object that holds all the information?

Comment: try like this - @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>
        Hello, `@User.Identity.Name`
    </text>
}

Comment: @AndreiV no, i am picking empID from database

Comment: Then use `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { <text> EMPLOYEE @empID has Logged in</text> } else {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
@if(Session["Employee"] != null) {
    int empId = 0;
    int.TryParse((string)Session["Employee"], out empId);
    <text> <strong>@empId </strong> has logged In <br />
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log In", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but please consider changing your `if` statement to `@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)`.